# If p is a non-constant polynomial and R>0 such that all roots of p lie inside $B_R(0)$, compute $\int_{B_R(0)} \frac{p’(z)}{p(z)}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I want to do the following:

If p is a non-constant polynomial and R>0 such that all roots of p lie inside $B_R(0)$, compute $\int_{B_R(0)} \frac{p’(z)}{p(z)}dz$

I believe that the answer is $2\pi i n$, where n is the number of roots of the polynomial. I got this answer using Residue Theorem.

However, I would like to evaluate this integral without using this theorem. Does anyone know of such a way to evaluate this integral?

My second thought was, since the degree of the numerator is strictly less than the degree of the denominator, to use partial fraction decomposition and assume that the zeroes were distinct. Then the integral could be split up into n many integrals over the ball centered around each zero with sufficiently small radius to assume they don’t intersect. Then, each of these n mant integrals has value $2\pi i$, so the integral is $2\pi i n$.

Comment: You can use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic on this, and factor both $p'$ and $p$ as a product of linear polynomials of the form $(z - \alpha_i).$ Repeated roots of $p.$ I suggest starting with the quadratic case, and you can figure out how the general argument goes from there, based on the ways that roots will or will not repeat in $p$ will give you an understanding of how $p'$ affects your computation.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand how to apply your hint. I started by trying to look at $p(z)=(z-a)(z-b)$, a quadratic with two distinct roots an and b. Then $p’(z)=2z-(a+b)$. But then the integral of $p’(z)/p(z)$ doesn’t seem to have simplified much. You could maybe split the integral into two integrals, but that doesn’t seem like it would be very helpful

Comment: Cauchy implies that the integral you want is the same as the integral on the circle of radius $\rho>R$; let $\rho \to \infty$ and show that the limit is precisely $2\pi i$ times the ratio of the leading coefficients of the two polynomials (since the numerator has degree one less than denominator) which is $n$ the degree of $p$ (hence the number of its roots by the fundamental theorem of algebra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of algebra implies that the considered $n$-degree polynomial can be rewritten as $p(z) = a(z-z_1)\cdots(z-z_n)$, where $a$ is a complex coefficient and $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ its roots. Then, the integrand takes the following form :
$$
\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} 
   = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \ln p(z) 
   = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \left(\ln a + \sum_{k=1}^n \ln(z-z_k)\right) 
   = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{z-z_k},
$$
hence
$$
\oint_C \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} \mathrm{d}z = \sum_{k=1}^n \oint_C \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-z_k} = 2\pi in
$$
by the residue formula.