# Using Residue Theorem to find constant a and b

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have the following question:

Let $p(z)=az^2+bz+2020$, $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$\displaystyle{ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial B_2(0)} z \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}}dz=0$ and $\displaystyle{ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial B_2(0)} z^2 \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}}dz=-2$
Determine a and b.

My guess to start this problem was to use the Residue Theorem, however I'm not sure how I would go about doing this, as the Residue Theorem says that the first integral above is equal to the sum of the residues inside the circle centered at 0 of radius 2, but I don't quite see how this helps.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: write the integral in a different form, e.g. use your prior thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4787023/if-p-is-a-non-constant-polynomial-and-r0-such-that-all-roots-of-p-lie-inside-b .  Then apply Cauchy Integral Formula.  How much can you progress with this?

Comment: @user8675309 I feel so silly for not thinking to use that! I will give that a try and see how far I can get :)

Comment: @user8675309 Using the idea from that thread, we can write $\displaystyle{\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}}$ as $c(\displaystyle{\frac{1}{z-z_1}+\frac{1}{z-z_2}}$, where $z_1,z_2$ are the zeroes of $p$. However when I use CIF I to get that $z_1+z_2=0$ and $2\pi i (z_1^2+z_2^2)=-2$, which feels like I've done something wrong?

Comment: shouldn't it be $z_1^2 + z_2^2 =-2$ and $z_1 + z_2 = 0\implies b =0$, now solve for $a$?  These integrals are giving you *power sums* of the roots btw.

Comment: Oh yes of course, the $\frac{1}{2\pi I}$ was already accounted for in the original integral! Thank you so much!